# I'm having trouble with php while loop inserting data in to mysql database

Tags: php, database, mysqli, while-loop

All the php code is below.

The script works fine up until the insert in to cinema database table part. I've echo'd
the contents of the variables each run through the loop to ensure that they have all
the correct data inside them. But for some reason some of the data is not being inserted in to the database even though it is contained in the variables just before the insert statement. There are 18 loops all together, but only 12 rows of data are being inserted in to the database. I thought maybe its too much data for one insert statement so tried limiting it to ten, then I planned on selecting the rest using the from id desc query, but of the first 10 only 7 inserted telling me that it must be the insert statement, not the database table. I have searched for a reason and tried lots of different things but still no joy. This is literally a last resort for me, as I am very much a DIY person and don't like asking for help. Thanks in advance for any help I get!

```
<?php

require('../php/connect.php');

$table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cinema (
    id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tags VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    image VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    link VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id))";

$result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $table);


$select = "SELECT * FROM search";

$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $select);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r , MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
{
    $tags = $row['tags'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $link = $row['link'];

    echo $tags;
    echo $title;
    echo $description;
    echo $image;
    echo "$link <br />";
    echo "one <br /><br />";

    $insert = "INSERT INTO cinema (tags, title, description, image, link)
                VALUES ('$tags', '$title', '$description', '$image', '$link')";

    $run = mysqli_query ($dbc, $insert);                        
}


if($result) {
    echo 'success';
}

else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: Any error information available?

Comment: Is it possible that any of those variables contain a `'`? Try prepared statements, they work perfectly for this use case.

Comment: revoua thanks for your reply. No its not saying there is any errors. just not inserting all the the data.

Comment: John thanks for your reply. I am not too familiar with prepared statements. and it is possible that some of the variables could contain a ' would that cause a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use the LOW PRIORITY keyword in your insert statement to avoid redundancy when the data is large.

```
INSERT LOW PRIORITY INTO cinema('a','b','c') VALUES('x','y','c')
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your code not inserting all data, it might be possible that the data which you are inserting might contain duplicate `ID` which is a primary key so that particular insert statement is failing.

Suppose:- You are executing loop 10 times(10 rows), then it might be possible that out of 10 rows 3 rows contain duplicate `id`(a primary key) so 3 insert statements are not getting executed.

Comment: He is using mysqli_ functions.

Comment: Oh... I didn't see it :P

Comment: Also, the duplicate logic will not kick in since cinema table has a primary key with auto-increment and OP is not inserting primary key values in the insert query. The PK duplicate error comes in when you explicitly try to insert a value for a primary key when it already exists.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I think he edited the question. Initially he was trying to insert ID.

Comment: thanks for the replies. The ID is auto increment on the cinema table. The data is selected from another database table called search which has 18 entries and the id for that is also auto increment.

Comment: As far as I can see the only thing that you changed in your suggestion was the if statement at the end. I tried it anyhow but no joy!

Comment: I made the if statement a part of the while loop. Also, what do you get when do this before the start of the while loop: var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array( $r , MYSQLI_ASSOC )); exit;

Comment: array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["tags"]=> string(77) "nicolas cage and bad santas terry zwigoff team up for dark comedy lost melody" ["title"]=> string(78) "Nicolas Cage and Bad Santa's Terry Zwigoff team up for dark comedy lost melody" ["description"]=> string(182) "Nicolas Cage is not exactly known for taking on indie films, and Terry Zwigoff is no ones idea of a prolific filmmaker. Yet the two are teaming up for a new dark comedy Lost Melody." ["image"]=> string(27) "../cinema/pics/nic-cage.jpg" ["link"]=> string(82)

Comment: "http://thenewshut.com/cinema/nicolas-cage-and-bad-santas-terry-zwigoff-team-up.php" } that what came from the var_dump. had to out it in two comments because it was too long for one.

Comment: this means the control is going into the while loop. Can you echo the $insert query statement from within the while loop and see if that is a valid statement?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I echo'd it out but its way too much to comment here

Comment: you don't need to put it here. Just echo the statement on your screen and see if you are able to execute that statement directly into your database. This will help isolate the issue.

Comment: Ok I can see where the scripts going wrong but I'm not sure why. Its saying which particular loops have failed, but still I have no idea why they are failing

Comment: did you try raw queries directly with your database? are those working?

Comment: sorry havent commented back sooner, been really busy with work. I have realized what the problem is. When I originally inserted the data in to the mysql database, I escaped any single quotes there were in any sentences with a back slash. But when I grab the data and try to insert it in to a new table, the quotes are no longer escaped so some of the data is not inserting in to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $select);

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r , MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
{  
    $tags = $row['tags'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    $link = $row['link'];

    echo $tags;
    echo $title;
    echo $description;
    echo $image;
    echo "$link <br />";
    echo "one <br /><br />";

    $insert = "INSERT INTO cinema (tags, title, description, image, link)
            VALUES ('$tags', '$title', '$description',               
   '$image', '$link')";

    $run = mysqli_query ($dbc, $insert);                        

    if($run) {
        echo 'success';
    }
    else {
       echo 'failed';
    }       
}
```